# Parallel processing of async/await functions queue

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I am trying to process a queue, in parallel. I have an object array, and I need to apply function `func` to each element, in parallel. I am making the parallelism level of chains as below:

```
async function() {
  const pickUpNextTask = () => {
    if (this.internalQueue.length) {
      return this.func(this.internalQueue.shift())
    }
  }
  const startChain = () => {
    return Promise.resolve().then(function next() {
      console.log('before then(next)')
      return pickUpNextTask().then(next)
    })
  }
  let chains = []
  for (let k = 0; k < this.parallelism; k += 1) {
    chains.push(startChain())
  }
  await Promise.all(chains)
  this.drain()
}
```

It is not working like I want to. The pickUpNextTask() ends-up returning `undefined` when the queue is empty, so there is no then.

How does one deal with this?

Comment: `pickUpNextTask` has no `else` with a `return` statement. Doesn’t it actually return `undefined` then?

Comment: Good point. It is `undefined`. Thank you.

Comment: Your code looks like you're trying to sequence things in the queue, not executing the 2nd item until the 1st one has finished.  But, your question says you want parallel processing.  Which do you actually want?

Comment: @jfriend00 please note that i have `this.parallelism` numbers of `queues`, as in multiples.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, it was easy enough:

```
  const pickUpNextTask = () => {
    if (this.internalQueue.length) {
      return this.func(this.internalQueue.shift())
    } else {
      return Promise.reject()
    }
  }
  const startChain = () => {
    return Promise.resolve()
            .then(function next() {
              return pickUpNextTask()
                .then(next)
                .catch(() => {
                  return Promise.resolve()
                })
            })
  }
```

Comment: Why use a promise rejection to detect the end of the chain? Rather put the `if`/`else` in the `next` function.